# Sluggish HD movies on Lenova Y550 with Geforce 240M

Tags: nvidia, video, hd-video

I have a ***Lenova Y550*** Laptop with dual boot ***12.04 LTS*** and ***Windows 7***. My graphics card is ***Nvidia Geforce 240M***. In windows ***HD movies (2 GB to 4 GB)*** are playing so smooth and I didn't find any sluggishness till date, But in Ubuntu it is different. Video hangs and gets interrupted frequently and it is impossible to watch movies. I have installed Nvidia accelerated graphics driver(version current) which is the recommended one from Ubuntu.

What should I do to make things same as that of Windows ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what video player you are using, but I'd recommend using VLC as it includes it's own codecs, and therefore handles just about any video format.

You can install VLC by going into Ubuntu Software Center, searching for VLC, then click Install.

Alternatively you can make sure you've installed all the correct codecs by going into a terminal window and typing:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-plugins-ffmpeg
```

Comment: I am a VLC fan and I am using it for windows and ubuntu for a long time. I have installed the packages you suggested. I think they do not have anything to do with VLC. Whatever; the situation continues...I am not able to watch HD movies with bigger size. I think it has a connection with the video driver...@codacube, what do you think ? –